# They have some background strong

Tags: meaning, subcontinental-english, sentence-meaning

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the expression "background strong". The line in the title is quoted from a movie, "Dying to survive". Here is some frame: an indian oil shop owner wants to import from India a cheap copycat medicine for CML (which is a form of leukemia) and therefore he holds talks with an indian man who is helping him with his supply. At some point the company producing the genuine drug realized that the market is being flooded with the fake one and sues the indian government in order to prevent the production of the copycat drug. The supplier says the following while trying to explain the situation to the shop owner:

"Some said India is a pharmacy for the poor because we have a merciful government, but right now the Swiss Nuowa company is suing the Indian government, trying to stop us from producing cheap medicines. They have some background strong. No country would dare to buy medicines from us. No country."

[Audio clip](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1yK5vkjXZ9x).

I can't understand the meaning of that "background strong"... could you please provide a rephrase or synonym for this? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
[image]

**EDIT 2:** [Here](https://soundcloud.com/user-318770137/tracks) are two tracks to compare "Strong" and "Cheng" pronounciations.

Comment: I think he’s saying “background strengths”, not background string (which makes no sense).

Comment: @Xanne: I tried listening at it with Astro A40 headsets I use for gaming (they're used in official tournaments) and I have no doubt that he says the sentence in the title.

Comment: @Xanne: Added a picture to my question.

Comment: What's the name of the guy in the denim blue shirt? if it's Cheng, and it seems likely because he  is East Asian, the answer is the protagonist is talking to his listener. You've done so much work and effort to support your question, which is hugely admirable but I sincerely believe that you and those who added the movie subtitles are wrong.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: what about the fist?

Comment: What about the fist, what has that got to do with the English language? It's a hand gesture with a pretty universale meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Just that it makes sense he's saying "strong" (if you have any headsets try listening the second audio I posted, I think you can recognize a 't')

Comment: Definitely not "strong" -- sounds like "chum".  The prior words are hard to make out -- could be "background", could be "bad grounds", could be something else.

Comment: I listened to the clip several times. I'm completely sure he is not saying "strong". The whole phrase sounds like either "they have some bad grounds, Chung" or "they have some backgrounds, Chung". His intonation in the last few syllables also makes the last syllable sound like a name said after the point he's making. (*Could* also be "chum", as others have suggested. That would also fit the intonation that makes me think it's a name.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pakistani here. The usual phrase is "strong background", but can be used as: His background is strong. It's used fairly commonly across the border here in Pakistan as well. He didn't use the exact phrase in the audio, though but that's what he meant.

"Strong background", when applied to a person, means that they either wield influence, belong to an influential family, or are protected by someone of influence. By "background", the speaker means their overall status in society, and by "strong", the speaker means elevated.

Pakistani society is full of sycophants, as I'm sure is Indian society, so anyone with slightly elevated status is well regarded. Similarly, the phrase "military background" may be used not just for someone that once enlisted in the army, but their children, siblings, parents and cousins as well. I say *may* be used because it really shouldn't be, and some people prefer not to identify themselves by their relatives. Generally, though, family units are extremely close-knit in the subcontinent.

By the by, what he says is:

> Some said India is a pharmacy for the poor...because we have a merciful government. But right now the Swiss Nova company is suing the Indian Government. Trying to stop us from producing cheap medicines. They have some backgrounds [*sic*] Chung. No country will dare to buy medicines from us, no country.

Chung is either the character's name, or—more likely—a nickname the speaker gave to the Asian character, on account of him being Asian.

Edit: I misread the question and misquoted it. Fixed.

Edit 2: He pronounces Chung as Chh-ung, which may be a mispronunciation of Cheng, but he's certainly referring to his co-star in the scene. He's using a softer "ch", which is a Hindi/Urdu sound, but not an English sound. See [IPA Hindi & Urdu](https://hif.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:IPA_for_Hindi_and_Urdu) for "چھ" but that aside, don't read too much into it. Hindi/Urdu stresses and pronunciations can aren't strictly adhered to unless the speaker is explicitly trying to be proper. We have two types of K's in Urdu: the ک and the ق but messing them up is a common occurrence.